# Problem expanding Raid 6 array on 64 bit Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, 64-bit, raid

I currently have a raid 6 array running on my 64 bit Ubuntu server (14.04) that runs a Plex server for me.  I have 8, 3TB disks in the array and the max usable space is 16.37 TB but the largest I can make the array is 15.58 TB.  Is this some kind of Ubuntu limitation or do I have another problem?  And, can this problem be fixed or will I need to transfer all my files, 13.6 TB, and re-format the array and transfer the files back?  Running fdisk -l I get the following information.

```
Disk /dev/md0: 18002.7 GB, 18002740248576 bytes 
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, -1 cylinders, total 35161602048 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 3145728 bytes
```

If more info is needed I can provide it.

Comment: Your space is 18002.7 Gigabytes, so 16,37 Gibibytes (gibi refers to 1024 so powers of 2). Fdisk show that you have 18 GigaBytes in your md device, that is correct size of an raid 6 array with 8 disks sized 3 terabytes. How is your filesystem created in top of md0?

Comment: I formatted the drive in ext4 when I initially created the array as a raid 5 with 5 disks and later converted it to raid 6 after a disk failure.  When I tried to resize the array after my most recent hard disk addition, I think I recall getting an error stating "New size too large to be expressed in 32 bits."  Not sure how that could be since it was all created using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: I used resize2fs to expand the array when I got that error.

Comment: I did some searching and it looks like it is a known issue with ext4 and 64 bit support.  It looks like I will need to update to 16.04 and update e2fsprogs to at least version 1.43 to be able to expand the drive beyond the 16 TiB limit.

Comment: ext4 has nothing to do with your raid6 block device size. I answered only that part. Your block device is exactly 18 terabytes, if your filesystem laying on it, is smaller, ask question why my ext4 is not growing to fill my entire block device. Keep drive and filesystem separated when you think data storage.